# jQuery cycle - bug if the pointer is over the rotator area on loading?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cycle

I notice [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EAVDZ/3/) problem on cycle :

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

<div id="rotator">
    <div>Ciao 1</div>
    <div>Ciao 2</div>
    <div>Ciao 3</div>
</div>

$("#rotator").cycle(
    {
        fx: 'fade',
        sync: 1,
        speed: 500,
        timeout: 800,
        pause: 1
    }
);​
```

if I go over the mouse in the rotator area, while the page is loading, the cycle crash (and only "sometimes").

Why? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in document ready event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rotator").cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        sync: 1,
        speed: 500,
        timeout: 800,
        pause: 1
    });​
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:-

```
$("#rotator").cycle(
    {
        fx: 'fade',
        sync: 1,
        speed: 500,
        timeout: 800
    });​
```